# Can I replace an inner tube with a Dunlop valve with one with a Schrader valve?

Tags: valves

I've accidentally bought an inner tube with a Schrader valve for a bicycle that's currently fitted with Dunlop valves. Can I still use it or they require holes in the rim of a different size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answer**: Yes you can.  Woods/Dunlop valves have a nominal hole size of 8mm, identical to a Schrader/Auto valve.

For completeness, a presta valve uses a 6mm hole.

Reasons not to - authenticity of an antique bike, or maybe having to carry a second pump head/fitting if both tubes have different valves.

Comment: Thanks. To be clear, these are modern Dunlop valves, which are very common around here (Netherlands), and with which it's even possible to read the pressure while pumping. As for the pump heads, I have a frame pump where it's just a matter of reversing a pastic part inside to switch between Schrader and Presta/Dunlop.

Comment: @Artefacto Do not underestimate the probability of losing said plastic bit when you are cold, wet and tired, cycling home in the dark. Do not overestimate the probability of finding said plastic bit when you are cold, wet and tired cycling home in the dark, near grass.

Comment: @Aron there are no rubber parts on these valves afaik. These are by far the most common valves in city bikes around here. I quickly surveyed the dozen or so bikes parked in front of my house today (all city bikes) and all but one (which had presta valves) had Dunlop valves. At work I parked near what looked like a single-speed road bike and that had Schrader valves though. It seems to vary by bicycle type.

Comment: @Artefacto My point was that, out in the cold, taking apart your pump so that you can pump a Schrader valve can often leave you with a broken pump.

Comment: @Aron ah, _that_ plastic bit. Sorry, I hadn't got that.